# How to load image with Picasso to simple View?

Tags: android, picasso

I need to load image using Picasso/Glide into View, not ImageView.But there isn't such method. Are there any probabilities?

Thanks everyone for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Picasso, you can load into a `Target`, like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(xyz).into(new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                     // Load the bitmap into your view
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed() {

                }
            });
```

Then you can do with the bitmap whatever you want, like loading it into a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want don't want Glide to insert the image directly into an ImageView, then you can always just load the image and do what you want with it, for example:

```
Glide.with(getContext())
    .load(uri)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            // Do anything with the new Bitmap resource you have
        }
    });
```